# How should I reference a Delta table with pySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-lake

I'm having difficulty referencing a Delta table to perform an upsert/merge on it after creating it new.  Doing it via pySpark with a typical `dataframe.write.format("delta")` terminology works fine.  When manually creating a table with the Delta table builder API create syntax,

```
deltaTable = DeltaTable.createIfNotExists(spark)
                .location("/path/to/table")
                .tableName("table")
                .addColumn("id", dataType = "String")
                ...
                .execute()
```

I can see the folder exists in storage as expected, and can verify that it's a Delta table using `DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, tablePath)`

The problem I encounter is when running `someTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, tablePath)` , then I get an error indicating that

*pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: A partition path fragment should be the form like 'part1=foo/part2=bar'*

Whether I do or don't explicitly partition the table in the create statement doesn't seem to matter.  I am trying to read the whole table, not a single partition.

So the question is, how do I reference the table correctly to load and manage it?

I'm using Azure Data Lake Gen 2 blob storage, though I'm not sure that's part of the issue.

As it's part of a question, my full path used for location is  *abfss://container_name@storage_account_name.dfs.core.windows.net/blobContainerName/delta/tables/nws*, where *nws* has business meaning.

Comment: This error should be triggered by `partitionPathParseException`. Could you share the location string that you use?

Comment: location string is  /delta/tables/nws, where "nws" has business meaning.  The fully qualified path used for location is then  abfss://container_name@storage_account_name.dfs.core.windows.net/blobContainerName/delta/tables/nws.  And my table isn't really called table, but you get the idea.